# Using three-finger drag and three-finger back on browser

Tags: macos

For OS X Lion 10.7, is there a way that I can use three-finger drag and still be able to use gestures to swipe "back" in Firefox or Chrome?

I've found out how to do one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use both. Maybe a third-party app will come along to support it or it may in the future, but not now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try going into system prefs -> mouse (or trackpad) -> more gestures, and use this arrow (picture below) to change the default options for gestures.

[image: arrow to use]